# Find the average of a list of items in C# with multiple parameters and grab an indexed element from the list

Tags: c#, list, average

I want to perform some calculations on my list `List<StudentGrades> studentList` such as the average, mean, mode, etc.

The `studentGrades` class has the following properties:

- `studentName`,
- `midtermGrade`,
- `finalExamGrade`.

How do I extract a certain property from the list and perform arithmetic operations on it?

The following code expands on the `StudentGrades` class.
I'm thinking of using some sort of traversal technique to add the elements together, something like `studentList.find(i).getMidtermScore` , which leads to my next question.

```
public class StudentGrades
{
    public string studentName;
    public int midtermGrade;
    public int finalExamGrade;

    public StudentGrades()
    {
       //initialize variables to 0 or ""
    }
   
    //some methods here
    //example
    private void getMidtermScore()
    {
        return this.midtermGrade;
    }

   public string toString()
   {
       string result = "student: " + studentName + " midterm grade: " + midterm + ...etc;
       return result;
   }
}
```

Also, how does someone grab an element at a specific index from a list?
In Java, for `ArrayLists` or `Lists`, we use the `get(//some value)` method to do so.

Looking at the Microsoft docs documentation for C# list, the counterpart is the `find()` method? Not really sure.

Comment: `var max = studentList.Select(z => z.finalExamGrade).Max();` or `var max = studentList.Max(z => finalExamGrade);` may get you started.

Comment: `Also, how does someone grab an element at a specific index from a list?` I'd start with `var first = studentList[0];`

Comment: LINQ has clearly-documented, easy-to-use features to do exactly what you want. For any scenario where the built-in `Average()`, `Min()`, and `Max()` methods don't suffice, there's `Aggregate()`. See duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
myList.Select(x => x.midtermGrade).Average() //average of midterm grades 
myList.Select(x => x.midtermGrade).Min() //lowest midterm grade
myList.Select(x => x.midtermGrade).Max() //highest midterm grade
```

`myList[0]` gives you first element of the list.

`myList[0].midtermGrade` gives you midterm grade of the first element of the list

Comment: Thanks! So it's similar to an array, in terms of indexing elements.

Comment: List is a form of array